# Upload multiple file in laravel in 1 database table

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to do multiple file upload using laravel. i already put attachment [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MglN.jpg), multiple in my view.I am only using 1 table in my database which call notifications with all the detail inside. below are my database table

I already try for each but it keep saying that

> Call to a member function `getClientOriginalExtension()` on array

i search on another by creating another table call in database and link with with my notification table, the below code can only upload the single file

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $notification=new Notification();
    $notification->title = $request->input('title');
    $notification->description = $request->input('description');
    $notification->link = $request->input('link');
    $notification->department = $request->input('department');

    if($request->hasfile('attachment')){ 
        $attachments=$request->file('attachment');
        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
        $extension=$attachments->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $attachmentsname=time().'.'.$extension;
        $attachment->move('uploads/attachments/',$attachmentsname);
        $notification->attachment = $attachmentsname; 
        }
    }
    $notification->save();

    return redirect('/notifications')->with('notifications',$notification);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array change,

```
$attachments->getClientOriginalExtension() to 

$attachment->getClientOriginalExtension(),
```

this will save only one attachment, because you in your database you have one column, `$notification->attachment` , so once you loop it, it only keeps the last value of the loop,

you should create a new pivot table, name as notification_attachment,and use [eloquent relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships), then loop store the attachments in a new table,

if you are having isssue storing the attachments to you atttachments table,

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $notification=new Notification();
    $notification->title = $request->input('title');
    $notification->description = $request->input('description');
    $notification->link = $request->input('link');
    $notification->department = $request->input('department');
    $notification->save();
if($request->hasfile('attachment')){ 
                $attachments=$request->file('attachment');
                foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
                $extension=$attachment->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $attachmentsname=time().'.'.$extension;
                $attachment->move('uploads/attachments/',$attachmentsname);
                $notification->attachment = $attachmentsname; 
               $attachment = new attachments();
        $attachment->notification_id = $notification->id,
        $attachment->path = $attachmentsname,

                }
            }
    return redirect('/notifications')->with('notifications',$notification);

}
```

your code should look like this if you have a attachments table and model.

Comment: hi i already add a table call attachments. i done the save file and make new Attachment it save but it wont relations with my notifications , and i already put belong to notifications

Comment: what is the structure of the attachments table? attachments table should have the notification_id as a foreign key,  And in the notification model should have has many relation with the attachments table,

Comment: Can show me how, because my controlle request all input ,in my attachment  table got file as mediumtext and notfication_id as foreign,but i dunno how to assigned input for the attachment and link to my notification_id because is been hour i trying to soling this

Comment: i have updated the code, have a look, and provide your database structure, and do you have model for your attachments table, and update your code in the que as well, provide all the info with specific issue,

Comment: 1. Do i need to remove attachment from my notifications table and model
2. For the form do how do i pass the variable to my NotificationController is it same as above

Comment: yes, you have to remove the attachment from the notification table, in the model you need to have the relation.  and you dont need to use the notificationController, please update your code here, so that I can help you,

Comment: In my attachment model i have fillable notification_id and filename or i just need to put notification_id?and relation of (belong to (notification) as for my notification model i have all the input except for attachment  and relation of(hasmany(attachment) . Is this correct

Comment: In your attachment model you will have fillable notification_id and filename, and the relation of (belong to (notification) , and in  your notification db, you won't have attachment column, you will have the relation of (hasmany(attachment).

Comment: if possible add your table structure here,

Comment: class Attachment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'attachments';
    protected $fillable = ['notificaton_id','filename'];

}    public function notification { this belongto(notification)} //sorry i dont know how to put code in comment , this is my attachment model

Comment: In your notification table, there shouldn't be any attachment column. please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships for more info

Comment: ya need work, but do you know how to show each file upload

Comment: To show each file upload, you can use Broadcasting, Go through https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting documentation. or you can use notification, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait. 

Depends on your structure of the code and the use case scenario.